# Assigning object index to be available inside the object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object:

```
    var contacts = 
{
  'KxN5RVjE1zoGqrzYKOV' :
  {email: "dfdfdf@dfdfd.com", firstName: "Lora", lastName: "Did"},

  '-KxN7AkNyiVjMYReZzbQ':
  {email: "teste@test.com", firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Smith"},

  '-KxN743hpoTVWIqR75XD':
  {email: "user@test.com", firstName: "Polina", lastName: "Polina"}

};
```

I need to make it's key to be a value, so it will look like this:

```
var contacts = 
{
  'KxN5RVjE1zoGqrzYKOV' :
  {email: "dfdfdf@dfdfd.com", firstName: "Lora", lastName: "Did", id:'KxN5RVjE1zoGqrzYKOV'},

  '-KxN7AkNyiVjMYReZzbQ':
  {email: "user@test.com", firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Smith", id: '-KxN7AkNyiVjMYReZzbQ'},

  '-KxN743hpoTVWIqR75XD':
  {email: "user@test.com", firstName: "Polina", lastName: "Polina", id:'-KxN743hpoTVWIqR75XD'}

};
```

This is the code I have so far, which does not add anything, just console the same old object:

```
var results = Object.keys(contacts).map((key, id) => {
  var contact = contacts[key];
  Object.assign({}, contact, {id: key});
  console.log(contact);
});
```

Any thoughts what is it I am missing and  what else can I try?

Comment: Apart from the fine answers given, your solution would have worked too. You just had to `return Object.assign(...)`. `map` maps input to output. You returned nothing so `undefined` was returned implicitly for each key. That's why your solution gave `[undefined,undefined,undefined]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new object rather than modifying, you can try [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)-

```
var results = Object
    .keys(contacts)
    .reduce((newObj, key) => Object.assign(
        newObj, 
        {[key]: Object.assign({id: key}, contacts[key])}
    ), {})
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind modifying the original object, you can just use `forEach` loop through keys and add `id` to each element:

```js
var contacts = 
{
  'KxN5RVjE1zoGqrzYKOV' :
  {email: "dfdfdf@dfdfd.com", firstName: "Lora", lastName: "Did"},

  '-KxN7AkNyiVjMYReZzbQ':
  {email: "teste@test.com", firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Smith"},

  '-KxN743hpoTVWIqR75XD':
  {email: "user@test.com", firstName: "Polina", lastName: "Polina"}

};

Object.keys(contacts).forEach(key => {
  contacts[key]['id'] = key;
});

console.log(contacts);
```